# netbeans with javadoc generate argument names as arg0,arg1,…

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

I made jar from javadoc simply by ziping javadoc html pages and then I imported it to netbeans. Everything works well, but argument names are like arg0,arg1,… I check it in html javadoc and there are names normal.

Where is a problem?

Comment: I'm not sure NetBeans uses the javadoc to suggest argument names. It probably uses the source code instead. Tray to make another jar with the source code, and attach the sources jar to the library.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have sources. Looks like I have to live without parameter names...

Comment: You might have the creator of the jar compile a new one with added debugging information. Then the parameters will have proper names, too.